# Only bulleted list shown when using 'simplexml_load_file()' in PHP to read RSS Feeds

Tags: php, mysql, rss, simplexml

I only see bulleted list on a page when loading this script to read RSS feeds. What am I not doing right?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>RSS Feed Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    function fetchFeeds($url){
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($url);
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($feed->channel->item as $itementry){
    echo "<li><a href='$itementry->link' title='$itementry->title'.$itementry->title"."</a></li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo fetchFeeds("http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/ page is not `XML`, it's `HTML`. Try `RSS Readers` in http://www.cnn.com/services/rss/ page like `Top Stories` linked `http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss`

Comment: just like bora has said, its the homepage of all rss feeds, you need to pick/choose which rss you want in the table

Comment: When I do that, I only see bullet points on my page and no feeds fetched. I have corrected the link pointing to RSS feed page for top stories on CNN. Test that and see what it displays

Comment: @Bora, I have edited the code and the description of the problem, please check back and advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are not calling the proper rss url. That is just the homepage of the RSS feeds. You need to select one first. In this example, **Top Stories** is selected. Consider this example:

```
<?php

// top stories RSS
$rss_url = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($rss_url);
$title = (string) $xml->channel->title; // typecast the title
$items = array();
for($i = 0, $size = count($xml->channel->item); $i < $size; $i++) {
    // also one way to extract is to convert it to this
    // each item will become an array
    $items[] = json_decode(json_encode($xml->channel->item[$i]), true);
}

?>

<!-- just plain foreach loop -->
<h1><?php echo $title; ?></h1>

<?php foreach($items as $key => $value): ?>
<ul>
    <li><?php echo $value['title']; ?></li>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $value['link']; ?>"><?php echo $value['link']; ?></a></li>
    <li><?php echo $value['description']; ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $value['pubDate']; ?></li>
</ul>
<br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

[**Sample Output**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/r415q7)